# "th" in the text of a link in Chrome not appearing

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```html
<p id="whitePaper11" class="whitePaper linkMimic">12th Man &mdash; Go Hawks, Fly Alaska</p>
```

It appears correctly in IE but in Chrome, the "th" of 12th does not appear at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks fine in my Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any relevant CSS?

Comment: It's a plain text, it should works in chrome.

Comment: it display well in my Chrome, i think maybe you have CSS linked with id or class.

Comment: Do you see the problem when you run the code snippet here?